# Restore MySQL tables with data folder only?

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, disaster-recovery

I have many MySQL databases with many tables and I’m trying to figure out if I can restore all of it only using the content of my MySQL data folder.

Or should I just not bother and use the following instead?

```
mysqldump --all-databases > db_backup.sql
```

Comment: The question talks about _restoring_.  The code talks about _dumping_.  What do you have??

Comment: @RickJames I have the data folders and would like to use them to populate a new database.

Answer (score 2):

You *cannot* move a single table or database around via the filesystem.

If you have the *entire* folder, then there is a pretty good chance of being able to move (or restore) *all* databases.

- `ibdata1` must be included
- Same version of MySQL.
- directory and file permissions need to be maintained
- and probably other things.